# ParseError at [row,col]:[12,337]

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I got the below error in Android Studio even though there is no mistake in my manifest.xml file. Anyone, please resolve my problem.

**ParseError at [row,col]:[12,337]**

Message: http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xml-names-19990114#AttributeNSNotUnique?RelativeLayout&layout_width&http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android

This is my Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tttbackup">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TTTBackup">
        <activity android:name=".Code"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Game" />
        <activity android:name=".Menu" />
        <activity android:name=".Splash">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: This is not from the manifest. Do you have layouts where you have used a Relative layout or layout tag?

Comment: All code that you post are inside <manifest></manifest> tag?

Comment: The problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I hade same problem in my application.
it is basically an xml exception.
in my case it solved when i removed   android:layoutDirection="rtl" attribute from "<layout"  container which i was using for dataBinding